# Get URL parameters for bokeh application

Tags: python, bokeh

Hi I am developing a bokeh application to perform some analysis. I want to get the URL parameters from the server so I can decide which data to render in the application.

Currently I can route URLs like `http://127.0.0.1:5006/bokeh/videos/?hello=1` with the following configuration, but is there a way I can get the GET parameters `{'hello':'1'}` from the application?

```
@bokeh_app.route("/bokeh/analysis/")
@object_page("analysis")
def make_analysis():
    app = AnalysisApp.create()
    return app
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Flask (which Bokeh server is built on), you'd access url parameters using:

```
from flask import request

@bokeh_app.route("/bokeh/analysis/")
@object_page("analysis")
    def make_analysis():
    args = request.args
    app = AnalysisApp.create()
    return app
```

(the request object gets added to the function scope by the app.route decorator)

Comment: Just add here that `from flask import request` is needed to access `request`

Comment: Just noting that this answer is out of date and incorrect.

Comment: What is the current solution?

Answer (score 17):

Easier way: a dict of (param name, value) is available in `curdoc().session_context.request.arguments`.

For your URL `http://127.0.0.1:5006/bokeh/videos/?hello=1`, it would give `{'hello', '1'}`.

Comment: See for example: https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#accessing-the-http-request

Comment: I think this is better answer than getting flask involved.

Comment: `from bokeh.plotting import curdoc`

Comment: How do we deploy so that URL contains the extra ?hello=1 bit. Using bokeh serve my URL address is hostname:port/my_app.py. How do I change this?

Comment: @A.DS: you deploy sour SERVER with host and port, not with extra routes or parameters that are hit by your CLIENTS.

Comment: I used just the hostname and port. when accessing it automatically opens at hostname:port/my_app.py. But when adding the extra bit hostname:port/my_app.py/hello=1, it throws 404 error.

Comment: Beware, port/my_app.py/hello=1 is not the same as port/my_app.py/?hello=1 (note the question mark for GET parameters)