# Control Bokeh plot state with HTTP Request

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm creating a bokeh application, and would like to make the state (widgets, which affect the figure) "shareable". My first thought was to use a query string in the URL. However, I'm not sure if the actual HTTP request is available to the application.

An example:

```
# main.py
from bokeh.models.widgets import Select
from bokeh.plotting import Figure
from bokeh.io import curdoc, vform

p = Figure()
selector = Select(title="Select", options=["1", "2", "3"], value="2")

p.line([1, selector.value], [1, selector.value])

curdoc().add_root(vform(p, selector))
```

which is served with `bokeh serve main.py` and accessed at `http://localhost:5006/main`.

If I navigate to `http://localhost:5006/main?select=3`, is there a way for the application to know that the original request included `select=3` and have that reflected in the figure going up to 3 instead of the default 2? Or am I approaching this entirely the wrong way, and missing a better solution?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32316959/get-url-parameters-for-bokeh-application) question and answer is related, but I think out of date now that bokeh server is built on tornado.

Comment: The HTTP Request is not currently available as of Bokeh 0.11.1, but it could be and various ideas have been suggested here and there. If you are interested in contributing to the direction of this development I encourage you to share your thoughts here: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/3349

Comment: Thanks. I'll follow along there and chime in if I see anything.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I was able to get this working. I'm not sure I would really recommend anyone use this code, but in case it's useful....

I wrapped the Bokeh application in a Flask app. The basic idea is to parse the query parameters in the flask view, and walk the Bokeh document, updating the objects as directed by the query parameter.

I updated `main.py` to include `state`, a list of widgets controllable by the query parameter

```
# file: main.py
# ...
state = [selector]
# ...
```

We import that in `app.py`, the Flask (or Django/whatever) app.

```
# file: app.py
import json
from urllib.parse import urlencode

from flask import Flask, request, render_template

from bokeh.client import pull_session
from bokeh.embed import autoload_server
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    session = pull_session(app_path='/main')
    doc = session.document
    update_document(doc, request)  # this is the important part
    script = autoload_server(model=None,
                             app_path='/main', session_id=session.id)
    return render_template('index.html', script=script, session_id=session.id)


def update_document(doc, request):
    '''
    Update a Bokeh document according to the query string in ``request``

    Parameters
    ----------
    doc: Bokeh.Document
    request: flask.request

    Returns
    -------
    None: (Modifies doc inplace)
    '''
    for k, v in request.args.items():
        # titles must be unique
        model = doc.select_one(dict(title=k))
        v = parse_query_value(v)
        model.update(value=v)


def parse_query_value(v):
    '''
    Parse a single parameter's value from the query string

    Parameters
    ----------
    v : str

    Returns
    -------
    parsed : object
    '''
    if v.startswith('['):
        return json.loads(v.replace("'", '"'))
    return v


@app.route('/state/<session_id>')
def get_state(session_id):
    '''
    Get the current widget state.

    Parameters
    ----------
    session_id : int
        id of the connection to the bokeh server from ``session.id``.
        this should be unique per tab.
    '''
    session = pull_session(app_path='/main',
                           session_id=session_id)
    doc = session.document
    params = {}
    for key in state:
        params[key] = doc.select_one(dict(title=key)).value
    return urlencode(params)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

And  `index.html`

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class='title'>Title</h1>

    <div class="plot">{{ script|safe }}</div>

  </body>

</html>
```